# How do I chain multiple filters on Postgres database using Golang with supabase?

Tags: postgresql, go, supabase, postgrest

So I have a supabase postgres database setup and I'm trying to use gin to setup an API for that database. I'm using nedpals/supabase-go to connect to my supabase client. I'm trying to chain multiple filters based on the request parameters like so:

```
func GetCardsByAdvanceSearch(supabase *supa.Client) gin.HandlerFunc {
    fn := func(context *gin.Context) {
        sets, isSets := context.GetQueryArray("setCode")
        colors, isColors := context.GetQueryArray("color")

        var results []any

        err := supabase.DB.From("cards").Select("*").Execute(&results)

        if(isColors) { results.In("colors", colors)}
        if(isSets) { results.In("set_code", sets)}

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        context.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "Results": results,
        })
    }
    return gin.HandlerFunc(fn)
}
```

This is based off the Supabase JS documentation that allows multiple "In" filters. But when I try to do it I keep getting errors where `results.In undefined (type []any has no field or method In)` basically `In` is not an applicable method on results even though it should be based on the docs.

Help please lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is effectively doing something like this:

```
var results []any
results.In("colors", colors)
```

`results` is a slice so, as the error states, "has no field or method In".

[`In`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/nedpals/postgrest-go/pkg#FilterRequestBuilder.In) needs to be run against the filter before you execute the query; something like the following (untested!):

```
srb := supabase.DB.From("cards").Select("*")
if(isColors) {srb.In("colors", colors)}
if(isSets) {srb.In("set_code", sets)}

var results []any
err := srb.Execute(&results)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new to Go so I didn't realize it was just returning a slice. This worked like a charm. Bless!